# How to show that randomized policy cannot be optimal for an MDP

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am working on Markov Decision Process and try to show that randomized policy cannot be optimal for a MDP. Is there anyway to prove that if there is an optimal policy for a MDP, then it must be deterministic?

Thank you

Comment: See this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44677/is-there-mdps-markow-decision-process-which-have-a-non-deterministic-optimal-p